# Why this.var cant be change JS?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a `this.val` in constructor, and I am assigning to `this.val` false value but this value is automatically overwritten when I run a different class element this value is only changed locally. My intuition tells me that this line`this.stats = this.createCreature(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange);` can make this strange behavior. Why this happening ? And how work `this.val` declared in constructor ? My code is ok when i use `localStorage` but this is only for test how can i fix this, finally i want to avoid this method

creature.js

```
import CreatureStatistics from './creatureStatistics.js'

export default class Creature {
    constructor(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange) {
        this.stats = this.createCreature(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange); 
        //<= line Up can make this error
        localStorage.setItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`, this.stats.getMaxHp())
        localStorage.setItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`, this.stats.getMaxHp())
        this.val = false; //<= declaring this.var
    }
    createCreature(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange) {
        return new CreatureStatistics(
            (_name || 'Smok'),
            (_attack || 1),
            (_armor || 1),
            (_maxHp || 100),
            (_moveRange || 10))
    }
    attack(_defender) {
        if (_defender.isAlive()) {
            let defenderDamageToDeal = this.calculateDamage(_defender);
            localStorage.setItem(`${_defender.stats.name}CurrentHp`, defenderDamageToDeal)
            if (_defender.isAlive()) {
                let attackerDamegeToDeal = _defender.calculateDamage(this)
                localStorage.setItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`, attackerDamegeToDeal)
            }
        }
        this.val = true;//<= changing this.val to true
    }
    calculateDamage(creatureToAttack) {
        return creatureToAttack.stats.getMaxHp() - this.stats.getAttack() + creatureToAttack.stats.getArmor() > creatureToAttack.stats.getMaxHp()
            ? creatureToAttack.stats.getMaxHp()
            : creatureToAttack.stats.getMaxHp() - this.stats.getAttack() + creatureToAttack.stats.getArmor()
    }
    isAlive() {
        if (localStorage.getItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`) > 0) {
            return true 
        }
    }
    getCurrentHp() {
        console.log('aaa', this.val) //<=This console.log return false
        return localStorage.getItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`)
    }
}
```

creatureStatistics.js

```
export default class CreatureStatistics {
    constructor(_name, _attack, _armor, _maxHp, _moveRange) {
        this.name = _name;
        this.attack = _attack;
        this.armor = _armor;
        this.maxHp = _maxHp;
        this.moveRange = _moveRange;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name
    }
    getAttack() {
        return this.attack
    }
    getArmor() {
        return this.armor
    }
    getMaxHp() {
        return this.maxHp
    }
    getMoveRange() {
        return this.moveRange
    }
}
```

Unit Test where all class are called

attackTest.js

```
import Creature from '../creature.js';

export default class AttackTest {
    constructor() {
        this.notImportant = 0
    }
    creatureShouldLost10HpWhenAttackerHas20AttackAndDefenderHas10Armor() {
        let attacker = new Creature('Attack', 20, 5, 100, this.notImportant);
        let defender = new Creature('Defender', 5, 10, 150, this.notImportant);

        attacker.attack(defender)
        if (defender.getCurrentHp() != 140) {
            throw 'Exception: => Creature nie zadala poprawnie obrazen'
        }
    }
    creatureShouldNotSelfHealWhenAttackerHasLowerAttackThenDefenderArmor() {
        let attacker = new Creature('Attack', 20, 5, 100, this.notImportant);
        let defender = new Creature('Defender', 5, 100, 100, this.notImportant);

        attacker.attack(defender)
        if (defender.getCurrentHp() > defender.stats.getMaxHp()) {
            throw 'Exception: => Creatura uleczyla sie podczas ataku'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `this.val` instead. I'm not sure that could solve your problem but `var` is a javascript keyword

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi should not matter

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi if it was a clash with a keyword, there would be a whole different error. Likely SyntaxError. If the code executes, it's not that. Besides, keywords are only a problem if used on their own - a property name cannot clash with a keyword. `this.var` is syntactically valid code that will work as expected if you have `a = { var: "foo"}; console.log(a.var)`

Comment: My guess is there is a scope issue and `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: I am used `var` only for this question. Normal this variable has a different name. But the question is why this value is not changing globally ?

Comment: Please define exactly where dose your `var` is changed and is not expected to you

Comment: It would be better to create a `codepen` or `sandbox` sample and share it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/epascarello/pmuo1grc/ shows it changes. You are making an attacker and defender, are you getting them mixed up? Like you are confusing the logs for the defender for the attacker?

Comment: https://pasjonatprogramowania.github.io/Heros_III_JS/

Comment: All the properties you're setting in the constructor function of a class – using `this.prop = value` syntax – are said to be own properties of the instance derived from the class, hence they are not "global", i.e. those properties are not inherited from the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are changing the var value of the attacker and not the defender.

```
attacker.attack(defender)

attack(_defender) {
     if (_defender.isAlive()) {
         let defenderDamageToDeal = this.calculateDamage(_defender);
         localStorage.setItem(`${_defender.stats.name}CurrentHp`, defenderDamageToDeal)
         if (_defender.isAlive()) {
             let attackerDamegeToDeal = _defender.calculateDamage(this)
             localStorage.setItem(`${this.stats.name}CurrentHp`, attackerDamegeToDeal)
         }
     }
     this.val = true;//<= changing this.val to true
}
```

The **this** here is the attacker.

And when you invoke:

```
if (defender.getCurrentHp() != 140) {
    throw 'Exception: => Creature nie zadala poprawnie obrazen'
}
```

The **this** here is the defender (not changed = false).

Comment: Ok thx this make sens. But how can i change scope from `defender` to `this.val` when i want to use it as a global value for `defender` and `attacker`?

Comment: Considering that I don't know what is the purpose of this variable: If this is a global value you can pass it as an argument to Creature instances or keep a static property like Creature.val